# Replace multiple characters by their quantity with regex

Tags: java, regex, replace

I have a string that may look kind of like this: "aaaaffdddd" and want to replace characters that occur 3 times (or more) with [NUMBER_OF_CHARACTERS][ONE_TIME_THE_CHARACTER] - I am not very confident with RegEx, but I came up with "([A-z])(\1{2,})" to find exactly those. However, in javas String.replaceAll() I have no possibility to refer to the number of characters in a group (?) and if I use Matcher.appendReplace() and a StringBuffer I lose the rest of my string since the result should still include characters which do not occur 3 or more times.

The example above should encode to "4aff4d"

Comment: Then you didn’t use `Matcher.appendReplace()` correctly. You have to use it together with `find` and `appendTail` and if used correctly it will copy the non-matching parts of the source string. Look at the [API documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#appendReplacement(java.lang.StringBuffer,%20java.lang.String)) for a complete example.

Comment: Yes that indeed was my problem, I added appendTail just after I was done replacing all matches and that worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After using appendReplacement on a StringBuffer I had to call appendTail in order to rebuild the rest of the String. Thanks to Holger for his Suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

This is not easy as you cannot get # of matches in replacement part easily. Try this code:

```
Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("(?i)([A-Z])(?=\\1{2})");
String str = "aaaaffdddd";
Matcher mat = pat.matcher(str);
Map<String, Integer> charMap = new HashMap<>();
while(mat.find()) {
    String key = mat.group();
    if (!charMap.containsKey(key))
        charMap.put(key, 3);
    else
        charMap.put(key, charMap.get(key)+1);
}
System.out.println("map " + charMap);
for (Entry<String, Integer> e: charMap.entrySet()) {
    str = str.replaceAll(e.getKey() + "+", e.getValue() + e.getKey());
}
System.out.println(str);
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
map {d=4, a=4}
4aff4d
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this (not tested)

```
String str = "aaaaffdddd";
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([A-z])(\\1{2,})");
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
while (m.find()) {
  m.appendReplacement(sb, "" + (m.group(2).length() + 1) + m.group(1));
}
System.out.println(sb);
```